# PHP como pegar imagem, no formato hexa direto do MSSQL?

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou fazendo um sistema com **PHP** e já consegui colocar uma imagem ou arquivo word, diretamente, dentro do **MSSQL**, **SQLSRV**, sem precisar colocar, os mesmos, em uma pasta, mas não consigo buscar eles e exibir no formato normal. Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso? Essa recuperação de dados?
Código de inserção no banco:

```
$dataHex = bin2hex($nome_final);

$imagedata = file_get_contents($nome_final);

$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);


$sql = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[documentosSub] (id_fun, nome_documento, hexa, base64) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

$params = array($id_fun, $nome_final, $dataHex, $base64);

$stmt = @sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);

$pasta = $_UP['pasta'];
$pastaP = explode('/', $pasta);
$pasta = $pastaP[0];


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {

header("Location: teste.php?pasta=$pasta&id_fun=$id_fun&cc=$cc");
} else {
echo "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo, tente novamente";
}
```

Código para exibição:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM [RDO].[dbo].[documentosSub] WHERE id_fun='$id_fun' ";
$stmt = @sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
?>
<table align="center" width="400" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><b>Id</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Nome</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Download</b></td>
        <td align="center"></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $id_documento = $row['id_documento'];
            $nome_documento = $row['nome_documento'];
            $hexa = $row['hexa'];
            $base = $row['base64'];
            $binary_string = pack("H*" , $hexa);
            $base64 = base64_decode($base);

            $arquivo = $prefixo.'/'.$pasta.'/'.$nome_documento;
            $imgP = explode(".", $arquivo);

?>

    <tr>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $id_documento ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $nome_documento ?></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="<?php echo $arquivo ?>"><?php echo $nome_documento ?></a></td>
        <!--<td><?php echo $base64 ?></td>-->
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: O problema é que eu não estou usando a versão 5.4 do php que suporta hex2bin e o programa na qual estou rodando aqui é o Vertrigo, similar ao XAMPP, WAMPP, mas não tem atualização para o php 5.4. Estou com um mega problema na mão. Teria como converter a imagem ou doc para outro formato para o banco e depois desfazer a converção?

Comment: @GustavoSevero Edite a pergunta informando este motivo de não poder usar `hex2bin`, ou sua pergunta será fechada como duplicada.

Comment: qual a versão do php

Comment: Desculpe Caffé, mas de que forma você quer que eu edite a pergunta?

Comment: Oi Otto, é a versão 5.3

Comment: é interessante sempre colocar o maximo de informações possivel para que possamos ajudar....

Comment: Pra não perder a piada .... Gustavo acho que você é muito Severo

Comment: Consegui converter a imagem, antes de salvar no banco, como base64, mas também não estou conseguindo recuperar ela.

Comment: Conseguiu como ? tentou com a resposta que mandei ?

Comment: Simplesmente, fazendo isso:

$imagedata = file_get_contents($nome_final);

$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);

Comment: entao voce jogou ela no banco com base64 .... faz o base64_decode

Comment: o que tem no  $base64 ?

Comment: Você postou o código que está tentando utilizar. Bacana. Mas acho que agora não ficou claro qual problema você está enfrentando.

Comment: Caffé, o problema de antes, não consigo fazer a imagem aparecer na tela, ou um link para a imagem.

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que entendo do teu código, estás a ler a imagem para a base de dados, inserindo a mesma codificada em Base64. Depois estás a fazer o *output* da imagem diretamente no teu HTML.

Desta forma não resulta pois em HTML para apresentares uma imagem precisas de fazer uso do elemento designado para esse efeito, a tag [`<img/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).

#### Exemplo

Tag `<img/>` com imagem em base64:

```php
<?php

// gatafunhos que vem da base de dados em Base64
$minhaImagemEmBase64 = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

// output da tag HTML com os gatafunhos em Base64
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$minhaImagemEmBase64.'"/>';

?>
```

#### Ver exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/adxaufu9/)

Temos um ponto vermelho em Base64 a ser apresentado na página ao invés de estarmos a estabelecer um *link* para um ficheiro do tipo imagem.

Answer (score 0):

**Você pode usar 'pack' :**

```
$binary_string = pack("H*" , $hex_string);
```

Comment: Otto, não deu muito certo. Me retorno, apenas, o nome da imagem!

Comment: Como posso postar o código aqui, com a formatação, identação correta?

Comment: edita a pergunta coloca la que depois edito e formatacao

Comment: Pronto, postei o código.

Comment: pelo que vi você fez $base64 = base64_encode($imagedata); faz o contrario $base64 = base64_decode($imagedata); para exibir

Comment: mesmo assim ta muito estranho

Comment: Pq? Era pra funcionar?

Comment: deveria .... estou pensando uma forma de fazer isto melhor